# Listing all Feature Classes being used in ArcGIS Pro project using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class, list

I am trying to work out how to list all feature classes in ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Pro files. I have used this script in the past which works for .mxd but recently I have started using ArcGIS Pro which has another extension file. Can anyone clarify if they have attempted this in ArcGIS Pro as I have over 1000 feature classes that I would like a list of that are being used.

```
import arcpy
import os

mxdDir = r'C:\path\to\directory\of\MXDs'

mxdDict = {}

for mxd in os.listdir(mxdDir):
    mxdPath = os.path.join(mxdDir, mxd)
    mxdDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)

    for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdDoc, "", ""):
        if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
            ds = layer.dataSource
            if ds not in mxdDict:
                mxdDict[ds] = [mxd]
            elif mxd in mxdDict[ds]:
                pass
            else:
                mxdDict[ds].append(mxd)
```

Comment: How does this code work or not work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of minor changes and your code runs:

- `arcpy.mapping` is now `arcpy.mp` in Pro
- In Pro you loop through maps instead of data frames, though you were ignoring data frames in your orig code and just using the active one by default.

E.g.

```
import glob  # I used glob instead of os.listdir in case there's more 
             # than one filetype in the dir. However, ArcGIS Pro 
             # usually has a single .aprx in  a project directory,
             # so you way want to look into using `os.walk` 
             # and `fnmatch.filter` to handle subdirectories

import arcpy

aprx_dir = r'path\to\*.aprx'

aprx_dict = {}

for aprx_file in glob.glob(aprx_dir):
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_file)
    for m in aprx.listMaps():
        for layer in m.listLayers():
            if layer.supports("DATASOURCE"):
                ds = layer.dataSource
                
                if ds not in aprx_dict:
                    aprx_dict[ds] = [aprx_file]
                elif aprx_file in aprx_dict[ds]:
                    pass
                else:
                    aprx_dict[ds].append(aprx_file)
```

Comment: Thanks dude - I just tried it but struggling to get an output. In terms of if layer.supports DataSource, is there any changes required here

Comment: Nope, `layer.supports("DATASOURCE")` works for me and is mentioned in the documentation https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm

Comment: Sorry - What I keep getting is arcgis application has stopped working and terminates everytime i run the script. I have tried it run it directly from ArcGIS Pro python and also from python directly. Maybe the other option could be to split it to many .aprx files.

Comment: @cardiokhan check you can open the aprx in ArcGIS Pro, perhaps it's corrupted.

Comment: Yes it opens up. It is very slow but does open. I have also tried splitting to just one map instead of several, it still bombs out with the same issue :(

Comment: I run exactly the same code just replacing r'path\to\*.aprx' with r'C:\Users\myusername\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject\*.aprx'

Comment: I dunno, it works for me with every aprx I've tried.  Try on a simple one.